# How do I make a looping moviescript finish before stopping it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, adobe

I'm animating a leaking object where water drops are falling down. I want the leaking to stop as soon as I click on a different object. When I use stop(); it just stops and the water drops are stuck in the air. Of course I don't want this, how do I fix it?

```
Bloempoteetkamer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rotplanteetkamer);

Bloempoteetkamer.buttonMode=true;
Bloempoteetkamer.mouseChildren=false;

function rotplanteetkamer(evt:MouseEvent){
    Planteetkamer.play()
    Druppel.stop()
    Bloempoteetkamer.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rotplanteetkamer);
    Bloempoteetkamer.buttonMode=false;
    stop();
}
```

Bloempoteetkamer is the object that you have to click to stop the leaking.
Druppel is the waterdroplets that are falling down.
Planteetkamer is a different moviescript that plays when I click on Bloempoteetkamer.

Comment: How are we supposed to know without seeing any of your code?

Comment: Bloempoteetkamer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rotplanteetkamer);

Bloempoteetkamer.buttonMode=true;
Bloempoteetkamer.mouseChildren=false;

function rotplanteetkamer(evt:MouseEvent){
 Planteetkamer.play()
 Druppel.stop()
 Bloempoteetkamer.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rotplanteetkamer);
 Bloempoteetkamer.buttonMode=false;
 stop();
 
}




Bloempoteetkamer is the object that you have to click to stop the leaking.
Druppel is the waterdroplets that are falling down
Planteetkamer is a different moviescript that plays when I click on Bloempoteetkamer

Comment: Update your question, don't post your code as a comment

Comment: "Of course I don't want this" ... well, what *do* you want?

Comment: To finish the clip before stopping like the title says

Comment: See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082387/as3-button-to-stop-movieclip-after-its-finished-playing

Comment: Did you solve your problem?  For future visitors with a similar question it's helpful to indicate how you solved your question.  If a provided answer led to your solution (you have two good answers), you can accept one,  if not you can answer your own question and accept that.  If you're still having difficulty, update your question or comment on the current status/issue you're facing.

Answer (score 3):

You likely want to use `EnterFrame` option to check, during playback of the MClip (Druppel), if it has actually reached the final frame and only then should the MClip `stop()`.

Try like this :

```
Bloempoteetkamer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rotplanteetkamer);

Bloempoteetkamer.buttonMode=true;
Bloempoteetkamer.mouseChildren=false;

function rotplanteetkamer(evt:MouseEvent){
    Planteetkamer.play();
    //Druppel.stop();
    Druppel.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, check_if_LastFrame);
    Bloempoteetkamer.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rotplanteetkamer);
    Bloempoteetkamer.buttonMode=false;
    stop();
}


function check_if_LastFrame(target : Event) : void
{
    if (target.currentFrame == target.totalFrames) 
    {
        Druppel.stop();
        Druppel.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, check_ifLastFrame);
    }
}
```

Comment: Test the code as it is then let me know if any issues. Could not test it myself at present but generally that's how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Another more compact option is to use AddFrameScript.   The `addFrameScript` method injects code onto a specific frame of a MovieClip as if you had done so using the tools in Adobe Animate.

Here is an example that creates a reusable function to stop a movie clip when it next reaches it's last frame:

```
function stopClipAfterLastFrame(clip:MovieClip):void {
    //addFrameScript to the last frame that calls an inline function
    clip.addFrameScript(clip.totalFrames-1, function(){
        clip.stop(); //stop the clip
        clip.addFrameScript(clip.totalFrames-1, null); //remove the frame script so it doesn't stop again the next time it plays
    });
}
```

So, if you called `stopClipAfterLastFrame(Druppel)` that would stop it once it reaches the last frame.

> keep in mind addFrameScript is an undocumented feature - which means it may on some future flash player/AIR release not work anymore - though that's very unlikely at this point.  It's also very important to remove your frame scripts (by passing null as the function) to prevent memory leaks.